# Browser (firefox) keeps loading for long django processes

Tags: django, firefox, django-views

I am using django to perform some activity which takes quite a long time to finish ( around 2-3 hrs).

A django form is filled by the user and submitted to initiate the activity.
The view function does all the required functionality but when everything is finished, a HttpResponse is returned to tell the user that the activity is completed.

The problem is that while the process has been completed in the back-end, my browser(firefox) still keeps on loading instead of display the returned HttpResponse.

Can anyone advice me whether it is a browser issue or something wrong in my code.

views.py

```
def test(request) :

    if request.method == 'POST': # If the form has been submitted...

        form = TestForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid(): # All validation rules pass
            form_data    = form.cleaned_data

            ## Get the form data and use it
            output, error = executeCommand("##Perform the required action with the form data")

            if error == '' :
                return HttpResponse('Work Done !! Thanks')
            else :
                return HttpResponse('Error Occurred')

    else:
         form = TesForm() # An unbound form

    return render_to_response("test.html", { 'form' : form } , context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/) to pass the job off to the backend for processing

Comment: I am going to give it a try but can you brief me a bit about celery if possible.
I have two large tasks to be run in one view and display the output when both complete, so is celery a suitable choice for such circumstances